# Here We Are vs We Are Here

Tags: word-order

Can anyone tell me the difference between

> Here We Are

And

> We Are Here

Comment: What about ''Here are we'' ?

is it a correct sentence and in the same meaning with ''Here we are''?

Answer (score 1):

**We are here.**

This sentence means exactly what is says.

> Where are we?
>
> We are here. (pointing at a map)

**Here we are.**

This sentence is more idiomatic. It can mean that the speaker found/reached something after spending time. It can also emphasize that the speaker wants attention directed on something.

> Hmm... which website was that... (a person looking through their browser history).
>
> Ah, here we are. (the person found the website)

---

> Here we are! That was a long drive wasn't it? (upon reaching a destination)

---

> Where are you? There are so many people at this concert! (on the phone)
>
> Here I am! (waving hand for attention)

---

> Here it is. Isn't it beautiful? (showing off a new car)

Answer (score 0):

The phrase

> We are here

is used to tell *someone* your current location.
It is usually associated with pointing at a map or directly at your feet (to emphasize "right here").

It can also mean figuratively that

> [We are here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HrKmDgk8Edg&t=1m33s) *(for something or someone)*

we "stand" here either in support or in waiting.

> Here we are

can have different meanings

> 1) it can mean the same as "we are here"
>
> 2) it can be used to announce the arrival of *something*, for example, bringing a much anticipated cold drink to *someone* who is very thirsty, synonymous with "here you go"
>
> Here we are!
>   *finally, here is what you have been waiting for*

the understood meaning would depend on additional context.

Answer (score 0):

We are here.

Here we are.

Both are different in meaning.

In the former, you are simply referring to the place where you are. In the letter, you are telling somebody that you have arrived.

Answer (score -2):

*Here We Are* stresses *here*, while *We are here* stresses *we*.